# Jar file running on one RPI but not another RPI

Tags: java

I have two RPI's, a model B+ and a Pi 3 model B. They are both running Rasbian.

I have made sure they have the same Java JDK on both (1.8.0_131) but one will execute a jar file, whereas the other cannot find or load main class Index.

Any help please? I'm fairly new to all this, but have avoided asking the question for many weeks now while trying to solve this myself.

Thanks
Seb

Comment: Welcome to the site Sebastian. It would speed things along if you could edit your question (*don't use comments*) to include the specific error message you're receiving.